# Can't import menuinflator

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I am following a beginners guide to android programming and I cannot get menuinflator to import, I keep getting

> the import android.view.MenuInflator cannot be resolved

Does this mean I need to add a package to eclipse or is my code wrong in some way? I would really like to continue with the tutorial but I cannot get the example working.

the code is below.

```
package test.menus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflator;


public class TestMenusActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflator inflator = getMenuInflator();
        inflator.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant [*MenuInflatEr*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html).

Comment: I figured that out and came back to try and hide that horrible mistake, thank you so much. Guess the red underlines werent enough to tip me off.